# How to prepopulate ngModel in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have no idea how to pre-populate an ng-model in this circumstance that I have to use ngBind. I tried ng-init, but it's not working.

```
        <h6 ng-show="isOwner" ng-bind="currentMagazine.magazine_name" 
        contenteditable ng-model="currentMagazine.magazine_name" 
        ng-change="update()"></h6>
```

I have a seperate directive that binds contenteditable attributes to ngModelController.

The problem now is whenever I update the model, ng-bind will jump out and refresh the div element, resulting in the cursur going back to the beginning of the text, which makes it impossible for any user to type.

I tried ng-init in a fashion like this:

```
<div ng-init="magazineName = currentMagazine.magazine_name">
    <h6 ng-show="isOwner"  
     contenteditable ng-model="magazineName" 
     ng-change="update()"></h6>
</div>
```

It's not working. If I don't use ng-bind, then no text will show up.

Also I notice it might be related to this problem, when I type with space or delete key, they are escaped into HTML entities...so you get result like this:

[image]

Hopefully both of my problems can be solved! Thank you (it's a very frustrating day)!

Comment: Think you probably just want to populate the variable on the scope in your app.js file that defines your main module, show your js code so far http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2439-My-Experience-With-AngularJS-The-Super-heroic-JavaScript-MVW-Framework.htm <-- see the graph here, the feeling isn't personal everyone goes through the slump days

Comment: you mean in my controller, I write `$scope.magazineName = $scope.currentMagazine.magazine_name` ? Tried that..it doesn't work. The graph fits me haha. I'm in phase two right now, second time trying second time thinking about quitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app.js do this:

```
$scope.magazineName = $scope.currentMagazine.magazine_name;
```

In your HTML do something like this:

```
<input
    ng-show="isOwner"
    contenteditable
    ng-change="update()"/>
```

or

```
<h6 ng-show="isOwner"
    contenteditable
    ng-model="currentMagazine.magazine_name" 
    ng-change="update()">
        {{currentMagazine.magazine_name}}
</h6>
```

... though perhaps not, it's a bit difficult to gauge without seeing it... please make a jsfiddle or plunkr if you'd like to get more eyes on it.

If you're just trying to make some large text that is still editable and bound to the model it may be easier to just style an input for your needs.

Decided to play with contenteditbale since it's chance for me to learn something too... I can't seem to recreate the issue though:
http://jsfiddle.net/VSJQX/

I saw after doing this it wasn't updating the model, found another SO post that resolves that and included the changes here:

http://jsfiddle.net/VSJQX/2/

Comment: Actually the second one works! Gee how come I never saw this!

Comment: One bit question, do you know how to deal with Angular escaping HTML entities? Whenever I type `xxxx ` it turns the last ` ` the stuff I have on that picture.

Comment: Sorry not sure about that you may be able to create a filter to deal with it, but I haven't played with contenteditable html elements really so I can't say for sure.

Comment: I guess I probably should use `input` field instead..thanks anyway

Comment: In the updated fiddle I put there if you change blur to input you'll see it update immediately but I think this works in WebKit/FF but not Opera and IE since it depends on the input event coming from a contenteditable HTML element.  The HTML entities you see are necessary for the HTML to display an ampersand or blank space without text after it (or multiple blanks)

Comment: I used contenteditable directive from angularJS API:http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController -> check it out. It's similar to what you wrote. I used ngSanitize to stop escaping HTML entities safely and it works very well. ng-change is definitely to be blamed (capturing all actions), but it is more compatible with many browsers!